# Links in references broken

Tags: latex, bibliography, biblatex

I am using \bibliographystyle{unsrt} and have some issues after printing the references.

Firstly, some of the links go outside the defined range:
[image: broken links within references]

Here is how the entry from the .bib file looks like:

```bibtex
@misc{noauthor_representational_2021,
    title = {Representational {State} {Transfer}. {Verfügbar} von: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/{Representational}\_State\_Transfer\#{Einheitliche}\_Schnittstelle. {Abruf} 01/08/2021},
    copyright = {Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike License},
    url = {https://de.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Representational_State_Transfer&oldid=214173929},
    abstract = {Representational State Transfer (abgekürzt REST) ist ein Paradigma für die Softwarearchitektur von verteilten Systemen, insbesondere für Webservices. REST ist eine Abstraktion der Struktur und des Verhaltens des World Wide Web. REST hat das Ziel, einen Architekturstil zu schaffen, der den Anforderungen des modernen Web besser genügt. Dabei unterscheidet sich REST vor allem in der Forderung nach einer einheitlichen Schnittstelle (siehe Abschnitt Prinzipien) von anderen Architekturstilen.
Der Zweck von REST liegt schwerpunktmäßig auf der Maschine-zu-Maschine-Kommunikation. REST stellt eine einfache Alternative zu ähnlichen Verfahren wie SOAP und WSDL und dem verwandten Verfahren RPC dar. Anders als bei vielen verwandten Architekturen kodiert REST keine Methodeninformation in den URI, da der URI Ort und Namen der Ressource angibt, nicht aber die Funktionalität, die der Web-Dienst zu der Ressource anbietet. Der Vorteil von REST liegt darin, dass im WWW bereits ein Großteil der für REST nötigen Infrastruktur (z. B. Web- und Application-Server, HTTP-fähige Clients, HTML- und XML-Parser, Sicherheitsmechanismen) vorhanden ist, und viele Web-Dienste per se REST-konform sind. Eine Ressource kann dabei über verschiedene Medientypen dargestellt werden, auch Repräsentation der Ressource genannt.
So ist ein Online-Dienst, der lediglich unveränderte Seiteninhalte nach dem Internetstandard HTTP anbietet, bereits REST-konform. Dynamisch erzeugte Seiten folgen diesem Paradigma jedoch oft nicht. So bieten beispielsweise Nachrichtenseiten sich ständig ändernde Informationen mit sowohl unterschiedlichem Format als auch Inhalt an, die nur schwer automatisch verarbeitet werden können. Bliebe das Format unverändert, so wäre eine wichtige REST-Eigenschaft erfüllt. So wäre eine Webseite, auf der ständig die aktuelle Uhrzeit in immer demselben Format abrufbar ist, REST-konform.
Die Bezeichnung „Representational State Transfer“ soll den Übergang vom aktuellen Zustand zum nächsten Zustand (state) einer Applikation verbildlichen. Dieser Zustandsübergang erfolgt durch den Transfer der Daten, die den nächsten Zustand repräsentieren.},
    language = {de},
    urldate = {2021-08-01},
    journal = {Wikipedia},
    month = jul,
    year = {2021},
    note = {Page Version ID: 214173929},
    file = {Snapshot:/Users/username/Zotero/storage/2D7HXXHG/index.html:text/html},
}
```

I have a couple of links like this within the references and I am not sure how I can fix them. I tried a couple of things like \sloppy, \setlength{\emergencystretch}{8em}, etc., but didnt seem to fix the issue. Also my links are defined within the title of the reference, would it be possible to make them work when they are on more than one line? Currently they are all clickable, but in most cases the link is broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of manually trying to escape all the special characters in your urls, use the `\url{..}` macro to typeset them. You can get it by e.g. loading the `url` or `hyperref` package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@misc{noauthor_representational_2021,
    title = {Representational {State} {Transfer}. {Verfügbar} von: \url{https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer#Einheitliche_Schnittstelle}. {Abruf} 01/08/2021},
    copyright = {Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike License},
    url = {https://de.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Representational_State_Transfer&oldid=214173929},
    abstract = {Representational State Transfer (abgekürzt REST) ist ein Paradigma für die Softwarearchitektur von verteilten Systemen, insbesondere für Webservices. REST ist eine Abstraktion der Struktur und des Verhaltens des World Wide Web. REST hat das Ziel, einen Architekturstil zu schaffen, der den Anforderungen des modernen Web besser genügt. Dabei unterscheidet sich REST vor allem in der Forderung nach einer einheitlichen Schnittstelle (siehe Abschnitt Prinzipien) von anderen Architekturstilen.
Der Zweck von REST liegt schwerpunktmäßig auf der Maschine-zu-Maschine-Kommunikation. REST stellt eine einfache Alternative zu ähnlichen Verfahren wie SOAP und WSDL und dem verwandten Verfahren RPC dar. Anders als bei vielen verwandten Architekturen kodiert REST keine Methodeninformation in den URI, da der URI Ort und Namen der Ressource angibt, nicht aber die Funktionalität, die der Web-Dienst zu der Ressource anbietet. Der Vorteil von REST liegt darin, dass im WWW bereits ein Großteil der für REST nötigen Infrastruktur (z. B. Web- und Application-Server, HTTP-fähige Clients, HTML- und XML-Parser, Sicherheitsmechanismen) vorhanden ist, und viele Web-Dienste per se REST-konform sind. Eine Ressource kann dabei über verschiedene Medientypen dargestellt werden, auch Repräsentation der Ressource genannt.
So ist ein Online-Dienst, der lediglich unveränderte Seiteninhalte nach dem Internetstandard HTTP anbietet, bereits REST-konform. Dynamisch erzeugte Seiten folgen diesem Paradigma jedoch oft nicht. So bieten beispielsweise Nachrichtenseiten sich ständig ändernde Informationen mit sowohl unterschiedlichem Format als auch Inhalt an, die nur schwer automatisch verarbeitet werden können. Bliebe das Format unverändert, so wäre eine wichtige REST-Eigenschaft erfüllt. So wäre eine Webseite, auf der ständig die aktuelle Uhrzeit in immer demselben Format abrufbar ist, REST-konform.
Die Bezeichnung „Representational State Transfer“ soll den Übergang vom aktuellen Zustand zum nächsten Zustand (state) einer Applikation verbildlichen. Dieser Zustandsübergang erfolgt durch den Transfer der Daten, die den nächsten Zustand repräsentieren.},
    language = {de},
    urldate = {2021-08-01},
    journal = {Wikipedia},
    month = jul,
    year = {2021},
    note = {Page Version ID: 214173929},
    file = {Snapshot:/Users/username/Zotero/storage/2D7HXXHG/index.html:text/html},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\cite{*}

\bibliographystyle{unsrt} 
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the fast response! I'm using Zotero for managing my bib and when I enter the title with the url macro -> "Representational State Transfer. Verfügbar von: \url{https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer#Einheitliche_Schnittstelle}. Abruf 01/08/2021" 
it exports it in the .bib file as "title = {Representational {State} {Transfer}. {Verfügbar} von: {\textbackslash}url\{https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/{Representational}\_State\_Transfer\#{Einheitliche}\_Schnittstelle\}. {Abruf} 01/08/2021}"
so the macro doesnt work in this case

Comment: @igotPOWA That's what you get by hacking the title to show the url. The proper way would be to use a suitable style which shows the `url` field.

Comment: could you recommend an other bibliographystyle which also looks similar and allows to showcase urls with a text in front of the url? - > for example: "available from: <URL>"

Comment: @igotPOWA For example the `unsrtnat` style from the natbib package. If you need more control of how the result should look like, I would use biblatex instead of bibtex